# Python. Извлечение url со страницы

Tags: python, html, регулярные-выражения

Этот код анализирует страницу и извлекает URL-адрес для создания карты сайта. Вместе с url забирает и часть кода js. Как сделать так чтобы исключить js?

```
if (resp.status == 200 and
        ('text/html' in resp.headers.get('content-type'))):
    data = (await resp.read()).decode('utf-8', 'replace')
    urls = re.findall(r'(?i)href=["\']?([^\s"\'<>]+)', data)
    asyncio.Task(self.addurls([(u, url) for u in urls])
```

Получаются ссылки:

> http://google.com
>
> http://google.com/intl/ru/policies/terms/
>
> http://google.com/intl/ru/policies/privacy/
>
> [http://google.com/intl/ru/policies/terms/url}}catch(e){}if(window.location.hash)url+=window.location.hash;window.location.href=url;](http://google.com/intl/ru/policies/terms/url%7D%7Dcatch(e)%7B%7Dif(window.location.hash)url+=window.location.hash;window.location.href=url;)
>
> http://google.com/preferences?hl=ru
>
> [http://google.com/intl/ru/policies/privacy/url}}catch(e){}if(window.location.hash)url+=window.location.hash;window.location.href=url;](http://google.com/intl/ru/policies/privacy/url%7D%7Dcatch(e)%7B%7Dif(window.location.hash)url+=window.location.hash;window.location.href=url;)
>
> [http://google.com/f},0](http://google.com/f%7D,0))};}).call(this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте закрывающую кавычку к вашей регулярке

```
re.findall(r'(?i)href=["\']?([^\s"\'<>]+)["\']', data)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло!